# Different rules for abstract methods in abstract class and interface

Tags: java

We cannot declare abstract methods in interface as protected and default (even if we don't mention any access specifier (default) compiler takes it as public)

but we can declare abstract method in abstract class as protected and default.

Why there are different rules for abstract class and interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> we cannot declare abstract methods in interface as protected and defaul

the purpose of Interface is to just declare contract. your client will implement it and for that it must be `public`.

also field in interface are `public` `static` `final` by default, 
public you got ,static because it can't be instantiated without implementation and it must not be inherited also.

**Update:**
as per your question

> you want to apply some strict constraint which your implementor can't see ..then what is the use of abstract method in abstract class that must be implemented by any concrete class in the inheritance hierarchy...then no one will be concrete class

```
public class BaseAbstractClass {
  private Connection getConnection(){
      //somecode 

  }

  public boolean save(){
      //get connection and do something 
      //return ;
  }

//your implementor is left to implement it , he  can use save method but can'ge see what it does i mean i doesn't have access to getConnection
  public abstract void saveEntity();

}
```

Comment: abstrct method in abstract class also have a contract with subclasses which are going to give the implementation of a abstract method in abstract class..but they are free to declare as protected and default

Comment: thats where difference comes between interface and abstract class, interface are pure contract, where abstract class you can have some common strict implementation

Comment: still i have a confusion..i know that abstratc class can have both abstract methods and non abstract methods(implemented)but interface is 100% abstract class..in both cases some one going to implement the abstract methods otherwise they are marked as abstarct..but abstract classes are free to declare its abstract method as protected and default ..why

Comment: because suppose you want to apply some strict constraint which your implementor can't see ,these stuff you can put in protected,default, method

Comment: @Jigar Joshi :you want to apply some strict constraint which your implementor can't see ..then what is the use of abstract method in abstract class that must be implemented by any concrete class in the inheritance hierarchy...then no one will be concrete class

Comment: 1 you can have public method which calls a protected method now got the point ?

Comment: @Jigar Joshi :sorry..can you please explain me this one more time

Comment: @Jigar Joshi: i think.declare abstract method as protected gives no sense..because even if you are in a same package or in a differnt package you are going extend the abstract class..default means..who are all creating the abstract classes ..they use them for polymorphism as their own in a same package...

Comment: No it does make the sense in some case we need that behavior also

Comment: yes i accept your answer..protected void method()(in my concrete class)i tell that who ever going to extend my concrete class can use this method(also in a same package)..is it right..

Answer (score 6):

Because abstract methods of abstract classes are meant to be hooks for subclasses. On the other hand interfaces are not concerned with implementation details - they are only about *contracts* with the "outside world". And a protected method is an implementation detail.

Comment: i can't get you..can you give me one more explanation for this question..i know that abstract class must be extended..and interface must be implemented

Comment: the reason is mainly theoretical. interfaces define contracts, abstract classes provide partial implementations. In a contract you shouldn't define implementation details.